# How to Add all Dict to another dict

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I got a list of Dictionary and I want to insert the dictionaries of a list into MongoDB.

Example:

```
hat = [{'index': 0, 'transactions': [], 'timestamp': 1550213571.912593, 'previous_hash': '0', 'nonce': 120, 'hash': '00e193195361aafda9d5c05666197dabb58be28972345ef9a7f254a1d4ef1bf1'}, {'_id': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6', 'index': 1, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Zoyeb Mansuri', 'content': 'Zoyeb Mansuri', 'timestamp': 1550213596.8207283}], 'timestamp': 1550213598.8488019, 'previous_hash': '00e193195361aafda9d5c05666197dabb58be28972345ef9a7f254a1d4ef1bf1', 'nonce': 225, 'hash': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6'}, {'_id': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'index': 2, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Akshay Godase', 'content': 'Akshay Godase', 'timestamp': 1550214711.1368275}], 'timestamp': 1550214713.4285166, 'previous_hash': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6', 'nonce': 419, 'hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f'}, {'_id': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9', 'index': 3, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Raj Pandey', 'content': 'Raj Pandey', 'timestamp': 1550215521.8643162}], 'timestamp': 1550215524.8524983, 'previous_hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'nonce': 308, 'hash': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9'}]
mat = {}
for data in hat:
    mat.update(data)
collection.insert_one(mat)


Output : print(mat)
         {'_id': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9', 'index': 3, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Raj Pandey', 'content': 'Raj Pandey', 'timestamp': 1550215521.8643162}], 'timestamp': 1550215524.8524983, 'previous_hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'nonce': 308, 'hash': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9'}

Want output : {{'index': 0, 'transactions': [], 'timestamp': 1550213571.912593, 'previous_hash': '0', 'nonce': 120, 'hash': '00e193195361aafda9d5c05666197dabb58be28972345ef9a7f254a1d4ef1bf1'}, {'_id': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6', 'index': 1, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Zoyeb Mansuri', 'content': 'Zoyeb Mansuri', 'timestamp': 1550213596.8207283}], 'timestamp': 1550213598.8488019, 'previous_hash': '00e193195361aafda9d5c05666197dabb58be28972345ef9a7f254a1d4ef1bf1', 'nonce': 225, 'hash': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6'}, {'_id': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'index': 2, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Akshay Godase', 'content': 'Akshay Godase', 'timestamp': 1550214711.1368275}], 'timestamp': 1550214713.4285166, 'previous_hash': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6', 'nonce': 419, 'hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f'}, {'_id': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9', 'index': 3, 'transactions': [{'author': 'Raj Pandey', 'content': 'Raj Pandey', 'timestamp': 1550215521.8643162}], 'timestamp': 1550215524.8524983, 'previous_hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'nonce': 308, 'hash': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9'}}
```

And the last collection one just insert this in Mongodb.

When I do this it only inserts last data in List. But I want all Data in List.

Comment: can you please print the output dict that you achieve and the one you want to achieve? also, what does the last line, `collection.insert_one(mat)` do? Is it relevant to your question?

Comment: Done, adding the output and want output.

Comment: Your input and output don't make sense, though. Give a real [mcve].

Comment: Ok, i am doing the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert the dictionaries into MongoDB right?

so instead of:

```
for data in hat:
    mat.update(data)
collection.insert_one(mat)
```

use

```
for data in hat:
    mat.update(data)
    collection.insert_one(mat)
```

Your Database table will now contain all the data.

and also, I think you misunderstand how dictionaries work, or how your for loop worked in your example. You can't have a dictionary containing dictionaries in them without specifying a key.
so, if you really want dictionaries containing dictionaries; using your code, it would look something like:

```
counter = 1
for data in hat:
    mat[str(counter)] = data
    counter += 1
```

using a counter variable to serve as the key. the output will look like:

```
{'1': {'nonce': 120, 'index': 0, 'hash': '00e193195361aafda9d5c05666197dabb58be28972345ef9a7f254a1d4ef1bf1', 'transactions': [], 'timestamp': 1550213571.912593, 'previous_hash': '0'}, '3': {'nonce': 419, 'index': 2, 'previous_hash': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6', 'hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'transactions': [{'content': 'Akshay Godase', 'timestamp': 1550214711.1368275, 'author': 'Akshay Godase'}], 'timestamp': 1550214713.4285166, '_id': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f'}, '2': {'nonce': 225, 'index': 1, 'previous_hash': '00e193195361aafda9d5c05666197dabb58be28972345ef9a7f254a1d4ef1bf1', 'hash': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6', 'transactions': [{'content': 'Zoyeb Mansuri', 'timestamp': 1550213596.8207283, 'author': 'Zoyeb Mansuri'}], 'timestamp': 1550213598.8488019, '_id': '00fd435c1b48d4e8f7a32f6307ecac29512fe9ef1b8c09fc12e673ad203d62e6'}, '4': {'nonce': 308, 'index': 3, 'previous_hash': '00436460a0d4d3421e4bc5eec46885450f5ca8cacca9d23d480be19e6288129f', 'hash': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9', 'transactions': [{'content': 'Raj Pandey', 'timestamp': 1550215521.8643162, 'author': 'Raj Pandey'}], 'timestamp': 1550215524.8524983, '_id': '00c555c788027d2d657607ef8822fc7aba5667bea08956dfbd75671e163f28a9'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hat = [{dict1},{dict2},{dict3},{dict4}]
mat = {}

for data in hat:
    for key in data.keys():        
        mat[key] = data[key]
```

Comment: it is showing Error Dict object has no attribute key